# How to create a single sign in page for two different devise users (business, individual)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create an app which has two different types of devise users, individuals and businesses. How can I achieve this, knowing that devise gives me separate routes for each model( both will login with email and password?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own route for logging the users in. Devise has a method for signing in a user that you can use from your controller `sign_in` ([ref](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Sign-in-from-a-controller)).

`sign_in(User.find(params[:id]), scope: :user)`

An alternative would be to create roles for your users. Every user is the same (instance of `User`), but they could have different roles. Depending on use case, you could give users a "current role" so that they could switch roles when needed.

Roles in your case would be "business" and "individual". You could add in "admin" for yourself.